# Symfony 5.4, customize form to display year only

Tags: php, symfony, widget

The current buildForm with the year added

```
->add('year', DateType::class, array(
'label' => 'Select Year',
'widget' => 'choice',
'years' => range(Date('Y'), 2000)
```

The twig file to customize the month and day attributes, (this used to work)

```
{{ form_widget(form.year['day'], {'attr':{'style':'display:none'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.year['month'], {'attr':{'style':'display:none'}}) }}
```

[It currently displays this image, would like it to display the year only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHwgm.jpg)

I've tried changing the twig file, adding a class to the form builder, nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

If your field is just an integer, you can just use the `ChoiceType` directly. Set the `'choices'` option to your range of years and configure the `'choice_label'` option to use the value.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class YearType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
  {
    $builder
      ->add('year', ChoiceType::class, [
        'label'        => 'Select Year',
        'choices'      => range(Date('Y'), 2000),
        'choice_label' => function ($value) {
          return $value;
        },
      ])
    ;
  }

}
```

The above `YearType` renders as below:

```html
<form name="year" method="post"><div id="year"><div><label for="year_year" class="required">Select Year</label><select id="year_year" name="year[year]"><option value="2023">2023</option><option value="2022">2022</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option></select></div><input type="hidden" id="year__token" name="year[_token]" value="9f14.o4haGhHOQ5-4CrGAkoeXWo94meRfttZPMpyzdrCmQdw.ydIdciiXJsngeuvs98b6Frkwrrdo05sOW-TwDuXVKu2O3jUjcpw0xsJsiQ"></div></form>
```

If you need it to be a `DateTime` Build an array of choices filled with `DateTime`s

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class YearType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
  {
    $range = range(Date('Y'), 2000);
    $choices = [];
    foreach ($range as $Y) {
      $choices[$Y] = new \DateTime("Jan 1st $Y");
    }
    $builder
      ->add('year', ChoiceType::class, [
        'label'        => 'Select Year',
        'choices'      => $choices,
        'choice_value' => function (?\DateTime $year) {
          return $year ? $year->format('Y') : '';
        },
      ])
    ;
  }

}
```